# Finding a joint / bone in a character

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am using the following simple code to find a particular segment in a specific character; i.e. a basic hierarchical component access.

```
void Awake()
{
    GameObject brad = GameObject.Find("Brad");
    GameObject elbow = brad.Find("JtElbowRt");
}
```

But I get the following error:

> Static member `UnityEngine.GameObject.Find(string)' cannot be accessed with an instance reference, qualify it with a type name instead.

I have seen the posts related to this error message. They generally talk about `static` methods and variables that means the variable or method is not tied to an instance of a class, but I have no idea what that means in this context. I am just trying to find a particular joint. Static what and where? Could someone please help me understand this properly?

Comment: It means the `Find` method is a static method on `GameObject`, so you can't access it on the `brad` instance. You'll need to find another way to get the joint on the instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
void Awake()
{
    GameObject brad = GameObject.Find("Brad");
    GameObject elbow = brad.transform.Find("JtElbowRt").gameObject;
}
```